# How to import "old" ES5 code in ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, webpack, es6-module-loader

I have an `ES6` application (with `Babel 6.5` and `Webpack`) and it successfully imports my modules like this:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
```

I wanted to install https://github.com/robflaherty/riveted/blob/master/riveted.js (a plugin for Google Analytics), but as you can see, the code doesn't have something like `module.exports = ...`, it only defines a global variable `riveted`, but it has an apparently valid `package.json` pointing to `riveted.js`.

So doing something like

```
import riveted from 'riveted'
riveted.init();
```

throws an error:

> _riveted2.default.init is not a function

```
import riveted from 'riveted'
riveted.init();
```

```
import 'riveted'
riveted.init();
```

throws an error:

> riveted is not defined

```
import * as riveted from 'riveted'
riveted.init();
```

throws an error:

> riveted.init is not a function

How can I access riveted's init() function?

Comment: Try doing `import * as riveted from 'riveted'`

Comment: Are you trying to run this in a browser?

Comment: Yes @slebetman. @Anzeo thanks but this gives me a yet slightly different error `riveted.init is not a function`. By the way, `riveted` is correctly "installed" into `node_modules/riveted`.

Comment: @wnstnsmth Looks like you need to use the [exports-loader](https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/shimming-modules#the-file-sets-a-variable-in-the-global-context-with-var-xmodule--) to shim the module as it's not properly exported

Comment: Then just include riveted.js in a script tag before the rest of your script. There is no need to require. It is already browser code, not node.js code that you need to make work in a browser.

Comment: did you tried with `import { default as es6Module } from 'es5Module';` ?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use the webpack exports loader:

```
var riveted = require("exports?riveted!riveted")
```

See [the shiming modules overview](https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/shimming-modules#the-file-sets-a-variable-in-the-global-context-with-var-xmodule--) for details

Comment: this was a HUGE help to me in a project. thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

#### Step 1. modify `riveted.js`

Add some code after line 18.

```
    // Browser global
    root = !root && typeof self == 'object' ? self : root; // add this line
    root.riveted = factory();
```

Because the `this` is undefined when the file is imported by es6, we use `self` instead.

`self` is better than `window`, it works in both main thread and worker.

#### Step 2. modify your import path

like this:

```
    import './riveted.js';
    riveted.init();
```

The `./` or `../` is required for import js file directly.

Examples:

```
import `./file.js`
import `../file.js`
import `./a/b/file.js`
import `../a/b/file.js`
import `../../a/b/file.js`
```

Tested in chrome.