# load in vanilla ES5 js file into ES6 environment via import

Tags: javascript, javascript-import, es5-compatiblity

**Scenario**

As part of my prototyping process I wanted to bring in tween.js which I can do using a `<script>` tag on the html portion but I'd like to import this vanilla es5 file directly to my es6 files for various reasons.

What I'd like to do is something like

`import * as TWEEN from 'import * as TWEEN from 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tween.js/16.7.0/Tween.min.js'`

While that seems to load the remote file I don't seem to get methods like `TWEEN.Tween` etc etc. I suspect all the es5 is disposed of in some sort of closure vacuum > garbage collection.

**Question**

I realize I can clone this file locally but I'm hoping to streamline my one-off style prototyping by importing cdn files that aren't always es6 friendly. Is this feasible ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to import "old" ES5 code in ES6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36687661/how-to-import-old-es5-code-in-es6)

Comment: Why don't you use the [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@tweenjs/tween.js) instead? `npm i -S @tweenjs/tween.js` , then `import TWEEN from '@tweenjs/tween.js';` and off you go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to inject `Tween.min.js` which is hosted on CDN via `script` tag, it will be `UMD` module, which is not compatible with `ESM` modules.

But, instead of importing it like you describe above, you can use/call it via `window` object:

`window.TWEEN` inside your esm modules.

When `Tween.min.js` will be loaded and executed it will be attached to `window` object.

Just to make sure that you are load that script first separately on HTML side, before your esm scripts/apps, otherwise `window.TWEEN` might be undefined.

Comment: This was the "best" idea I could come up with, creating a non-attached script tag to load in the file separately.

Comment: yeah, so you can treat `Tween.min.js` as external library, which is not bundled into your esm app or script.